# NuGet Package custom package path

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I want NuGet to automatically download missing packages to a packages location outside of the solution 'globalpackages' folder.  I have amended the NuGet.Config file as per [this help page][1].

My solutions's `NuGet.Config` file:

```
<configuration>
  <solution>
    <!-- Disable source control integration of packages folder -->
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
  </solution>
  <config>
    <!-- Repository packages folder path -->
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="$\..\..\globalpackages" />
  </config>
  <packageRestore>
    <!-- Allow NuGet to download missing packages -->
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <!-- Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio -->
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
</configuration>
```

When looking in a project's .csproj file, the following references still exist:

```
<Reference Include="C5">
  <HintPath>..\packages\C5.2.2.5073.27396\lib\portable-net40+sl50+wp80+win\C5.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

This is pointing to the wrong folder.  Do I need to hard-update each of these references for each project?

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and NuGet 2.8

Answer (score 0):

Do not hard update each of the NuGet references. Just delete them and add the packages again.

Comment: I really do not want to go down this road.  We have many many packages used across 20 projects.  Is there really no other way?  Why cant I edit the project files?

Comment: Yes, if you are good at RegEx you can edit the project files and have the references updated in few seconds.

Comment: But you just said that I must not hard-update the csproj files?